# Adding more commands to Shell Startup script

Tags: android, shell

I used the following commands to create a startup script called usersuspend.sh

```
echo "sleep 2" > usersuspend.sh
echo "am force-stop com.android.deskclock" >> usersuspend.sh
```

The written file now looks like this:

```
sleep 2
am force-stop com.android.deskclock
```

The script forces the com.android.deskclock to close.

Question is: If I wanted the same script to close more applications should the file look like this:

```
sleep 2
am force-stop com.android.deskclock
am force-stop application2
am force-stop application3
```

If so, do I just simply keep running this command for each additional line:

```
echo "am force-stop application2" >> usersuspend.sh
```

Will this just append to the existing file? Does the double >> matter? because in the first line there is a single >

Answer (score 0):

> Will this just append to the existing file? Does the double >> matter?

Yes and yes - see the [manual](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm):

#### Input/output redirection

```
 …
 >file       Standard output is redirected to file. If file does not ex-
             ist, it is created; if it does exist, is a regular file, and
             the noclobber option is set, an error occurs; otherwise, the
             file is truncated. Note that this means the command cmd <foo
             >foo will open foo for reading and then truncate it when it
             opens it for writing, before cmd gets a chance to actually
             read foo.

 >|file      Same as >, except the file is truncated, even if the
             noclobber option is set.

 >>file      Same as >, except if file exists it is appended to instead of
             being truncated. Also, the file is opened in append mode, so
             writes always go to the end of the file (see open(2)).
 …
```